# Using Jquery to drag and drop, get value from dropped div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I am using Jquery to making drag and drop.

My short javascript to make an item to drag is:

```
$(".draggable").draggable();
```

My short javascript to make a dropable area is:

```
$("#droppable").droppable();
```

Here is my dragable item short HTML code:

```
 <div id="comItem[]" class="computerItem draggable">
    <img src="img/com.png" class="assetImg" alt="Computer Info" title="">
    <span id="owner[]" class="textLabel"></span>
    <span id="ipaddress[]" class="textLabel"></span>
 </div>
```

Does someone know how to get the values from dropped items in dropable area?
I want to create the object array form the dropped items?

Thank you so much.

Comment: are you using a library like jQuery ui?

Comment: Im using jquery & jquery-ui.

Comment: cerlin beat me to it, his answer should do

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `ui.draggable` object in `drop` action

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable).find('img'));
    }
})
```

Here `ui.draggable` is the element which you have dropped. (in this case the whole div)

Comment: Thanks, do you know how can i get the values in <span> which in the dropped div?

Comment: you can use `$(ui.draggable).find('span')`. this will return both the span tags

Comment: It work! Thank you so much. Can i ask another question? If there are many dropped div in the dropable area which is the same ID, how can i get all values in span?

Comment: the `drop` event will be called everytime when you drop an element. so, whenever a drop is happening get the values of the spans inside that and push it to an array/object. Finally you will have an array/object with all the dropped elements data

Answer (score 1):

You must use the drop event for droppable.  Here is what I mean.

```
var items;
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
    drop: function(event,ui) {
        items = [ui.draggable];
    }
});
```

Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wLkutytx/

Source: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop